# поиск в кластере карты

Tags: php, ajax, yandex-maps-api, cluster

http://createe0.beget.tech/corp-clients/

внизу страницы карта АЗС. Выводятся поярдка 5000 меток (все группируются в кластер).
В поле город можно вводить город и сделать фильтрацию АЗС по городу.
Сейчас это работает очень медленно. Можете подсказать в какую сторону двигаться для ускорения отрисовки после применения фильтра?

Comment: На самом деле не вижу серьёзных задержек в работе карты. Если после выбора региона сразу кликнуть в любую область страницы мимо карты, то все объекты сразу отобразятся. Это ваша анимация загрузки мешает только. Отключите её.

Comment: спасибо! Направили в нужном направлении!